# Why does this class-scope variable not get updated in recursive function?

Tags: python

I'm writing a small class for an LED controller, that runs as a process. The idea is that some code runs constantly to blink LEDs over an i2c bus.

I'm new to OOP with Python, and I'm also new to Processes in python. I'm using Multiprocessing with Python 3.4, but with the new print function should also run in 2.7x.

If you run the code, I add three things to the blinkgroup list, which is shown locally to have had an effect, however this never gets detected in the ledblinkloop function, which calls itself so that it keeps running.

I suspect I've fundamentally mis-understood something in Python here.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

class LedController(Process):
    def __init__(self):     
        super(LedController, self).__init__()
        print("ledcontroller started: ",self.name)
        self.blinkgroup = [0x04,0x05]

    def run(self):
        self.ledblinkloop()

    def led_blink_on(self,led):
        if(led not in self.blinkgroup):
            print("LED not in blink group, adding. New blinkgroup length:",len(self.blinkgroup))
            self.blinkgroup.append(led)

    def ledblinkloop(self):
        print("Length of blinkgroup:",len(self.blinkgroup))
        time.sleep(1)
        self.ledblinkloop()

class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        ledcontroller = LedController()
        ledcontroller.start()

        while(1):
            time.sleep(5)
            ledcontroller.led_blink_on(0x08)
            ledcontroller.led_blink_on(0x09)
            ledcontroller.led_blink_on(0x10)
            time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Code should run as is with Python 3.

Comment: Where exactly is there a class-level variable here?

Comment: If I'm using the wrong name, please feel free to edit. Is self.blinkgroup = [0x04,0x05] not a class-level assignment?

Comment: You have two processes with seprate LED objects.  You're appending to one of them, but the other one is in a separate process and has totally separate data.  (Also, `self.blinkgroup = ...` is an instance attribute, not a class attribute.)

Comment: You're using `self`, which means it's an object-level variable

Comment: ledblinkloop calling itself will eventually smash the stack as it never returns.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you all. Is it worth using Threading instead of Multiprocessing for this kind of application? (that would save having to use queue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The multiprocessing library works by spawning additional Python processes. They do not share memory.

I see you did import `Queue` from the multiprocessing library, but proceeded not to use it. That `Queue` is one of two ways you can communicate between `Process`es, the other being a `Pipe`.

Probably worthwhile to read through the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html) for the multiprocessing library before continuing.

Comment: Great, very helpful. Should I think about using Threading instead of Multiprocessing for this application?

Comment: @Chris That greatly depends on your needs. Threading is slightly easier to work with, but due to limitations in the Python interpreter, you cannot run Python code actually simultaneously in multiple threads, which means Threading is only really useful for I/O bound situations (when you're waiting for something external.)  
Multiprocessing was created to bypass this by running multiple separate processes. In this particular case, you should be able to use Multiprocessing.Queue quite easily.

Comment: Great, I'll use the manual to look at Queue and decide from there, but given I want to run many processes to look after various things (2 modems, LED i2c controller, GPS etc.) I think multiprocessing is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Chris Worthy to note, the queue datatype is very useful the moment you start doing stuff with multiple producers/consumers, so you'll definitely want to look into them. They're not too different from a list, except they are ordered, and you usually append stuff on and pop them off again, which is what you want. You might also want to look into synchronisation stuff like Locks to avoid race conditions, which tend to pop up a lot when you're doing multiple threads/processes.